# How to discover USB storage devices and writable CD/DVD drives (C#)

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

How can I discover any USB storage devices and/or CD/DVD writers available at a given time (using C# .Net2.0).

I would like to present users with a choice of devices onto which a file can be stored for physically removal - i.e. not the hard drive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
using System.IO;

DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
  if (d.IsReady && d.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
  {
    // This is the drive you want...
  }
}
```

The DriveInfo class documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

this is VB.NET code to check for any removable drives or CDRom drives attached to the computer:

```
Me.lstDrives.Items.Clear()
For Each item As DriveInfo In My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives
    If item.DriveType = DriveType.Removable Or item.DriveType = DriveType.CDRom Then
        Me.lstDrives.Items.Add(item.Name)
    End If
Next
```

it won't be that hard to modify this code into a c# equivalent, and more *driveType*'s are available.
[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.drivetype.aspx)

- **Unknown:**     The type of drive is unknown.
- **NoRootDirectory:**    The drive does not have a root directory.
- **Removable:**  The drive is a removable storage device, such as a floppy disk drive or a USB flash drive.
- **Fixed:**  The drive is a fixed disk.
- **Network:**    The drive is a network drive.
- **CDRom:**  The drive is an optical disc device, such as a CD or DVD-ROM.
- **Ram:**    The drive is a RAM disk.

Answer (score 1):

in c# you can get the same by using the System.IO.DriveInfo class

```
using System.IO;

public static class GetDrives
{
    public static IEnumerable<DriveInfo> GetCDDVDAndRemovableDevices()
    {
        return DriveInfo.GetDrives().
            Where(d => d.DriveType == DriveType.Removable
            && d.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete module for VB.NET : 
Imports System.IO 
Module GetDriveNamesByType 
    Function GetDriveNames(Optional ByVal DType As DriveType = DriveType.Removable) As ListBox 
        For Each DN As System.IO.DriveInfo In My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives 
            If DN.DriveType = DType Then 
                GetDriveNames.Items.Add(DN.Name) 
            End If 
        Next 
    End Function 
End Module

```
'Drive Types <br>
'Unknown: The type of drive is unknown. <br>
'NoRootDirectory: The drive does not have a root directory. <br>
'Removable: The drive is a removable storage device, such as a floppy disk drive or a USB flash drive. <br>
'Fixed: The drive is a fixed disk. <br>
'Network: The drive is a network drive. <br>
'CDRom: The drive is an optical disc device, such as a CD or DVD-ROM. <br>
'Ram: The drive is a RAM disk. <br>
```