# Accessing MP3 Player / USB Storage device

Tags: vb.net, file-io, usb-drive, fileinfo

I'm trying to access a USB Storage device, however the device although appearing in the computer / Drives section, is not allocated a Drive letter, thus when I iterate through the attached drives as described in [How to discover USB storage devices and writable CD/DVD drives (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51645/how-to-discover-usb-storage-devices-and-writable-cd-dvd-drives-c), it does not appear. I've taken the "Location" from a file on the drive (properties) and it comes up as `COMPUTER/Q1/Datacasts` but this doesn't work when I pass it to the FileInfo Object (network drive cannot be found), and I'm at a bit of a loss at which way to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more investigation I discovered it needed to be a windows Portable Device, and got some hints from [the MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpdblog/).